# Create RadialGradientBrush

Tags: wpf

I have the color # FFECE9D8, # FF716F64 how do I create a gradient brush

```
 RadialGradientBrush br = new RadialGradientBrush ();
 br.GradientStops.Add (new GradientStop ("# FFECE9D8", 0));
 br.GradientStops.Add (new GradientStop ("# FF716F64", 1));
```

Falls bug - new GradientStop ("# FF716F64", 1) - can contain a string

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ColorConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colorconverter.aspx)-class to convert a string to a color.

```
RadialGradientBrush br = new RadialGradientBrush ();  
 br.GradientStops.Add (new GradientStop ((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFECE9D8"), 0));  
 br.GradientStops.Add (new GradientStop ((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF716F64"), 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating the gradient in code instead of XAML, you cannot use strings to specify the colors. Just use Color.FromArgb() instead.

Your example then becomes this:

```
RadialGradientBrush br = new RadialGradientBrush();
br.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xEC, 0xE9, 0xD8), 0)); 
br.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x71, 0x6F, 0x64), 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Constructor of GradientStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602458.aspx) expects [Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.aspx), not string. You can do the following:

```
new GradientStop(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xEC, 0xE9, 0xD8), 0);
```